# How can i display images in React coming from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api-platform.com

I am trying to display the images from an API but I failed,
I am using API platform in the back-end

this is my API schema:

```
{
    "@context": "/api/contexts/Advertise",
    "@id": "/api/advertises/1",
    "@type": "Advertise",
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Eius vitae aut totam eius iste.",
    "description": "Aperiam quo nihil ad atque minima harum est. Omnis odio sint veritatis accusamus. Asperiores harum provident quas quas eum. Fuga rerum est error nemo voluptas aliquam similique.",
    "price": 1261,
    "published": "2019-08-30T20:50:06+02:00",
    "user": {
        "@id": "/api/users/13",
        "@type": "User",
        "username": "laurent03"
    },
    "images": [
        {
            "@id": "/api/images/1",
            "@type": "Image",
            "id": 1,
            "file": null,
            "url": "/images/5e22213525ba2416125688.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

**when I do**

```
{
    <p>
        {post.user.username} //it works
    </p>
}
```

**but when I try this**

```
<p>
    <img src={`http://localhost:8000${user.images.url}`} />   }  //it does not works
</p>
```

I don't know how to handle this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please replace this

```
<img src={`http://localhost:8000${user.images.url}`}
```

to

```
<img src={`http://localhost:8000${post.user.images[0].url}`}
```

It should point array element out and then object property.